# jqgrid guriddo - how to change height of pager

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I tried jqgrid guriddo the newest version and had problem with set height of footer (pager). 
I need increase height of pager.

I tried

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager { 
    height: 130px; 
}
```

or

```
$('.pager').css({"height":"130px"});
```

but didnt work.

Is it something like method `setGridHeight` for pager?
How can I sloved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the id of the pager you can just (suppose the pager has id=jqGridPager):

```
$("#jqGridPager").height(130);
```

after creation of jqGrid